# Passing PHP variable to Javascript dynammically added textbox

Tags: php, javascript

i have a javascript function like this:

```
function addfamily(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="family[]" size="16">';
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

which dynamically adds textbox to the form and a php script like this:

```
<?php
$result_family = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM family_member where login_id='$_SESSION[id]'");

$num_rows_family = mysql_num_rows($result_family);

if ($num_rows_family>0) {

   while($row_family = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_family)){

   echo "<script language=javascript>addfamily('family');</script>";
   }
}
```

having this code the textboxes are added fine.
i just need to know how can i set a dynamic value as the textbox value by passing the php variable `$row_family[name]` to the function and the value of the textbox???
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to pass the name of the Div along with $row_family['name'] your javascript function should look like

```
function addfamily(divName,familyName){
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='family[]' size='16' value=" + familyName + ">";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

and then the call from PHP should be like

```
echo "addfamily('family',$row_family['name']);";
```

HTH

Comment: wow,thank you very muchhhhhhh,god bless you!you really helped me alot

Comment: @adi - If this answer solved your problem, click the Accept Answer checkbox to the left of the answer.

Comment: Mixing PHP & JavaScript like that is bad practice ... but well done